# float element next to inline element with dynamic width

Tags: html, css, css-float

how to set float element next to inline element with dynamic width

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/J2Df8/

html

```
<div>
<span>Lorem ipsum dolor</span>
<span class="floater"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
DIV{
    width: 100px;
}


SPAN.floater{
    height:4px;
    width:4px;
    margin-top:3px;
    float:left;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this http://jsfiddle.net/J2Df8/12/

HTML

```
<div>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor<span class="floater"></span></span>    
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor<span class="floater"></span></span> 
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    width: 100px;
}

div span {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    padding-right:10px;
}


span.floater{
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    height:4px;
    width:4px;
    top:8px;
    right:0;
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: sorry but this is not good. if element is inline-block or block there is always extra space when text is wrapped. look at your example with firebug and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Comment: I think that this will always be like this.. because the span element is an block itself whenever has wrapped text or not..

Answer (score 0):

HI now used to `:after` in you span

**as like this**

```
span{
    width: 100px;
    display:block;
}


span:after{
    content:'';
    height:4px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:4px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
}
```

***[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/J2Df8/8/)***